# Linux Command to See Outbound Network Requests

Tags: networking

Is there a linux command that summarizes outbound network requests?

I'm specifically interested in seeing what the `git push` command sends to github (headers, body, etc) without having to download something like wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

With GitHub being TLS-encrypted with non-public secret keys, packet capture utilities like tcpdump, tshark (command-line Wireshark), and Wireshark won't likely provide the insight you're looking for (i.e., into application-layer messaging).

You could attempt to run your git commands through `strace`, which would reveal system calls and their arguments, including networking reads/writes.  Switches I've found useful:

`strace -ftttxys 128 -yy`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you have fairly low level debugging tools such as  `tcpdump` and `wireshark`.

As was [already answered here](https://serverfault.com/a/1105749/960939) that won't help you much when the traffic is encrypted.

For applications that use HTTP(S) as a transport protocol you can  run a HTTP proxy that does MitM SSL/TLS decryption and then configure the application to use that proxy to connect to the servers. For example:

- https://mitmproxy.org/ and https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/

And in general: simply running the application with sufficiently verbose debug flags will often also get you what you need.

For example git supports:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEPACKETcode
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEcode
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACECURLcode
  *Enables a curl full trace dump of all incoming and outgoing data, including descriptive information, of the git transport protocol.*